# Header is already set before flush and still getting "Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent"

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In the following code as I understand it I am sending the header before I fill the buffer with the pdf.  This is so the page header loads and the user sees that while waiting for the pdf to be fetched and serialized, etc...

This works fine 99% of the time but I am getting occasional errors in the log of "Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent".   How can that be happening using the following code?

Side note: I simplified the code and omitted the code where I am fetching and serializing the pdf.

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{

    if(AnyValidationFails){
        return;
    }

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("...")
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", pdfOut.Length.ToString());
    Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.Zero); // never let a proxy server cache it
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)); // let the browser cache it though. 
    Response.Flush();
    Response.BufferOutput = false;

    //couple more lines to get the pdf and set the buffer... 

    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: use a handler - and not the page its self

Comment: Can you help me understand?   What will putting that code in a handler do that solves the issue?

Comment: Because an aspx page can send header at some point that you can not control it - handler is empty and did not send anything